# QGIS auxiliary label locations: determining their storage locations

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes

**Background:**

Using 3.26.3, I have a Geopackage point layer that I can successfully move the label locations using the *Move Label* button (below).

[image]

In the past, this process has automatically added two new fields to the layer attribute table, *auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx* and *auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony*.

However, in this case, those fields were not created.  According to the layer's styling window (below), they were instead stored in the project.

[image]

This has confused me. I don't know how I caused the locations to be stored in the project. I would prefer to store them in the layer's attribute table, but the "Store data in the project" button is greyed out, preventing me from turning that off.

**Question(s):**

How do I convert this particular layer's label positions from the project to the attribute table?  In the future, how do I inform QGIS where I want the label positions to be stored?

**Postscript:**

The layer's properties window has an *Auxiliary Positions* tab that mentions a "qgd" file.  However, no such file exists for this layer.  How does the presence or absence of a qgd file impact my situation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When moving the first label, you must `Select the primary key to use for joining with internal data storage`.

### Solution 1

When this is created (as it is the case with you), you automatically find two new entries in expression string builder when you expand `Fields and Values`, named `auxiliary_storage_labeling_postionx` and the same for y.

Simply create a new field with field calculator using these two entries:

[image]

---

### Solution 2

There is another possibility: in the layer properties, go to `Auxiliary Storage` Tab. At the bottom, you find the option to export an Auxiliary Layer - a separate layer that contains attributes with the values of labeling_postion for x and y coordinates:

[image]

*Exported `auxiliary_layer`, labeled here with the `labeling_positiony` attribute: it appears only where initial red labels were moved:*
[image]

Comment: Your response (thanks!) answers the first of my two questions.  In retrospect, my second question was unintuitive; allow me to restate it here:  When I first moved the label, using the Move Label button, QGIS did **not** add the two *auxiliary_storage_labeling_position* fields to the layer's attribute table.  Instead, they were added to a qgd file (zipped in the project qgz file).  In my previous experience with moving labels, the attribute table was automatically edited to include the two position fields.  *In this particular case, why wasn't the attribute table automatically edited?*

Comment: I guess you should create a separate post for your second question as the policy of this site requires - here in the comments, the question risks to get lost.

Comment: Fair enough.  Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving this problem :

1- Make sure your layer have an id or unique field

2- When start working with the label moving tool, use that unique field as identificator